# Problem in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I am executing the following command in Makefile:-

```
@ls export_mojave/marker_*.tcl > export_mojave.list
@for file in `cat export_mojave_tcl_files.list`; do \
    diff $$file bk_marker > $$file.diff ; \
    if ! [ -s $$file.diff ]; then\
        rm -f $$file.diff ; \
    else \
        echo $$file >> marker.fill.tcl.diff; \
    fi \
done ;
```

If there exists some file related to the above expression in the mentioned directory,
it will run fine but if there does not exits any files matching to above expression, It is marking an error. Is there anything exists like "catch" in Makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to skip error in makefiles' rule, then prefix command with '-' sign:

```
-@ls .... > some_file || echo Error: no file;
if [ -e some_file ] ....
```

Or modify to be more in make-style:

```
FILES := $(shell ls ...)
ifeq ($(FILES),)
$(error no files)
endif
....

target:
    $(foreach file,$(FILES), ...)
```

Comment: I agree, we can ignore errors using "-". But I want return status of ls command.

Comment: Well, you can output stderr from ls to file and then check if it exists/print it..

Comment: Can we use FILES declaration inside target? If yes, how?

Comment: No you can't. If you really need that, I would propose recursive makefiles approach, i.e. when you pass control to sub-make by calling $(MAKE) -f print-diffs.mk + you can pass parameters to that sub-make

Comment: @amitesh maybe I didn't get you right, but declaration of make variable (FILES=...) cannot in rule, but you can use this variable anywhere after declaration.